# Read and Write into file every X line

Tags: c++, fstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream  stream1("source.txt");
    string line ;
    ofstream stream2("target.txt");

        while( std::getline( stream1, line ) )
        {
            stream2 << line << endl;
            cout << line << endl;
        }


    stream1.close();
    stream2.close();    return 0;
}
```

I want to make this program read every 10th line and write it into my file.

How do i go about doing this?

Comment: Cant you make use of some counters? Still you need to call getline every time, but only put it into stream of the other file when counter hits 10 and then re-initialize the counter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read every line and increment a counter. If the counter reach 10, you need to write the line and reset the counter.

```
int lineNumber = 0;

while( std::getline( stream1, line ) )
{
    if (lineNumber == 10)
    {
         stream2 << line << endl;
         cout << line << endl;
         lineNumber = 0
    }

    lineNumber++;
}
```

Comment: something wrong with your increment operator?? i dont c it. Also you need to assign lineNumber = 0 after it hits 10

Comment: Writing on stackoverflow from a tablet sucks... Should work now, but the formatting options aren't available.